# Mac installation Apache with SSL, WSGI

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, wsgi

I tried to install apache, apparently installation is done well and I can see the page localhost, also I set while the SSL but when I set the module wsgi I have problems because the page as FORBIDDEN appears, I uninstalled and I installed XAMPP But they problems, nose to follow steps for configuration and that have good results.

I'm installing on a Mac Yosemite

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Why are you trying to install a new Apache as Yosemite comes with a reasonably up to date version already? If you get forbidden, then it is going to be due to how you have configured mod_wsgi for your application in Apache, but you haven't provide any details of your Apache setup that you added, which makes it very hard to guess the problem.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/925280/mamp-in-mac-yosemite-ssl-wsgi

Comment: Really really i need help!